# Using functions in VHDL for synthesis

Tags: function, vhdl, synthesis

I do use functions in VHDL now and then, mostly in testbenches and seldom in synthesized projects, and I'm quite happy with that.

However, I was wondering if for projects that will be synthesized, it really is a smart move (in terms of LE use mostly?) *I've read quite a lot of things about that online, however I can't find anything satisfying.*

For instance, I've read something like that : "The function is synthesized each time it's called !!". Is it really so? (I thought of it more like a component instantiated once but whose inputs and output and accessed from various places in the design but I guess that may be incorrect).

In the case of a once-used function, what would change between that and writing the VHDL directly in the process for example? (In terms of LE use?).

Comment: You can prevent replication of complex functions by only calling them once and feeding multiple inputs to them through muxes or FIFOs as needed to trade parallelism for space. For simple functions it might not be worth the bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A circuit in hardware, for example a FPGA, executes everywhere all the time, where in compare a program for an CPU executes only one place at a time.  This allows a program on a CPU to reuse program code for different data, where a circuit in hardware must have sufficient resources to process all the data all the time.

So a circuit written in VHDL is generally translated by the synthesis tool as  massive parallel construction that allows concurrent operation of all of the design all the time.  The VHDL language is created with the purpose of concurrent execution, and this is a major different from ordinary programming languages.

As a consequence, a design that implements an algorithm with functions vs. a design that implements the same algorithm with separate logic, will have the exact same size and speed since the synthesis tool will expand the functions to dedicated logic in order to make the required hardware available.

That being said, it is possible to reuse the same hardware for different data, but the designer must generally explicitly create the design to support this, and thereby interleave different data sets when timing allows it.

And finally, as scary_jeff also points out, it is a smart move to use functions since there is nothing to loose in terms of size or speed, but all the advantages of creating a manageable design.  But be aware, that functions can't contain state, so it is only possible to create functions for combinatorial logic between flip-flops, which usually limits the possible complexity in order to meet timing.

Comment: Agree with all of this. To answer the "is this a smart move?" part, the answer is a solid "yes". If you have functionality that is repeated, you should always try to use an entity, procedure, or function for this, to improve code maintainability. If you have the functionality replicated in many different places, at some point, someone will make a change, forget to update one of the instances, resulting in a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should use functions and procedures.

Many people and companies use functions and procedures in synthesizable code. Some coding styles disallow functions for no good reason. If you feel uncertain about a certain construct in VHDL (in this case: functions), just type up a small example and inspect the synthesis result.

Functions are really powerful and they can help you create better hardware with less effort. As with all powerful things, you can create really bad code (and bad synthesis results) with functions too.